# Average distance function in python

Tags: python, distance

I am trying to solve the following question:

consider the following function

```
Point2D = tuple[int,int]
def average_distance(points: set[Point2D]) -> float:
```

that is given a set of points on the grid, where each point is specified by a pair of integer coordinates, and returns the average distance between all the pairs of distinct points in points. If there are less items in points than 2, the function raises ValueError.

**Example:
average_distance({(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)}) is approximately 3.7712**

I have spent quite a bit of time thinking how to implement this, but it does not come easy to me. I understand that you have to calculate the distance for all possible combination, and I have found the code below which works, and i partially understand. Can someone shed some light on this problem? at least how to approach in the simpliest way possible?

```
import math
from itertools import combinations

def dist(p1, p2):
    (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = p1, p2
    return math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)

x = [1, 3, 5]
y = [2, 4, 6]

points = list(zip(x,y))
distances = [dist(p1, p2) for p1, p2 in combinations(points, 2)]
avg_distance = sum(distances) / len(distances)
```

Comment: What parts don't you understand ? the `combination` line ?

Comment: Well, you seem to understand that the distance between two Cartesian (x,y) coordinates can be found by the square root of `(x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2` (effectively the Pythagorean Theorem). I'm sure you also understand that an average of a set can be found by the summation of each set element divided by the number of elements. That's all you're doing here: Summing each distance between points then dividing the result by the number of points.

Comment: I dont understand how to iterate over all possible combinations of values, in the example I have 3 coordinates which give out 3 combinations (1,2)(3,4) - (1,2) (5,6) and (3,4)(5,6), the function should be able to take in lenght. I hope it makes sense

Comment: Iterating through all combinations is done in the code via the `combinations` method from itertools (to produce the combinations you've mentioned, in sequence). So `combinations(points, 2)` should produce something like: `[((1,2),(3,4)), ((1,2),(5,6)), ((3,4),(5,6))]`. The list comprehension assigns each element of the previous list to `p1` and `p2`, in sequence. So first `p1` = `(1,2)` and `p2` = `(3,4)`. Then you call `dist(p1,p2)` to get the distance between those points and assign the result as an element in the new list, `distances`. Please see my answer for additional detail.

Answer (score 1):

The distance between two Cartesian Coordinates can be found by deriving the Pythagorean Theorem: `a^2 + b^2 = c^2`, which can be solved for `c` by `c = sqrt(a^2 + b^2)`. Here, the distance is measured by changes in `x` and `y`. That's why the Python formula works well: `math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)`

But that is just a single distance between two points. What if you want the average distance between all points? Well, the average is defined as the sum of all parts divided by the number of parts that were summed. In other words, you want to sum each distance, then divide by the total number of distances measured. That is what this is doing:

```
avg_distance = sum(distances) / len(distances)
```

Finally, we have `distances = [dist(p1, p2) for p1, p2 in combinations(points, 2)]`.

The `[dist(p1, p2) for p1, p2 in combinations(points, 2)]` here is what is known as a Python List Comprehension. Think of it as a bit of a for-loop that iterates through all possible combinations of points, assigning their values to `p1` and `p2`, calculating their distance with the `dist` function, then assigning the result to a new list, the `distances` variable. To produce each combination of points, you used the `combinations` method, providing a list of all points and the  number of points within each combination (2). It seems as if your primary confusion is with the `combinations` method. It certainly does a lot of the work for you. I suggest reading through the [itertools documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Identify all pairs of points

*All pairs of points* in this context are a set of all possible **2-element set of points** (pairs) in a given set of points.

For the pairs of points [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-frozenset) objects must be used, because the elements a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) must be hashable (immutable):

```
pairs = {frozenset({p1, p2}) for p1 in points for p2 in points - {p1}}
```

You can also use the [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) function from the `itertools` library which returns an iterator:

```
pairs = combinations(points, 2)
```

## 2. Calculate the average distance of all pairs

For each pair, calculate the [distance between it's points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Distance_between_two_points), then take the [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) of the distances.

You can use a generator expression and the [`mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) function from the `statistics` library:

```
average = mean(
    sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)
    for (x1, y1), (x2, y2) in pairs
)
```

---

The final function can look something like this:

```
from math import sqrt
from itertools import combinations
from statistics import mean


Point2D = tuple[int, int]
def average_distance(points: set[Point2D]) -> float:
    if len(points) < 2:
        raise ValueError("points has less than 2 elements")
    return mean(
        sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)
        for (x1, y1), (x2, y2)
        in combinations(points, 2)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.combinations` to list up all possible combination pairs. For example, in one dimention,

```py
pairs = itertools.combinations([1, 2, 3], 2)  # [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1])
ds = [math.abs(p, q) for p, q in pairs]. # [1, 1, 2]
ave = sum(ds) / len(pairs) # 1.333..
```

So is an answer

```py
import math
import itertools

def distance(p, q):
  return math.sqrt((p[0] - q[0])**2 + (p[1] - q[1])**2)

def calculate_average_distance(points):
  combinations = itertools.combinations(points, 2)
  distances = [distance(p, q) for (p, q) in combinations]
  num_combinations  len(combinations)
  average_distance = sum(distances) / num_combinations
  return average_distance

ave_d = calculate_average_distance([(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)])  # 3.7712
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: is there a simpler way to do this?  maybe nested foor loops?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to publish my solution which does not use any library and the recommended solution from the teacher which also does not use any library

```
Point2D = {(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (-3,6), (0, 18)}

def average_distance(Point2D):
  Point2D = list(Point2D)
  distances=[]
  if len(Point2D) < 2:
        raise ValueError
  for i in range(len(Point2D)) :
    for y in range(len(Point2D)):
  #   print (Point2D[i][0], Point2D[y][0])
  #   print (Point2D[i][1], Point2D[y][1])

      x1, x2 = Point2D[i][0], Point2D[y][0]
      y1, y2 = Point2D[i][1], Point2D[y][1]

    #   print (x1, x2, y1,y2)
      
      mydistance = (sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2))
      round(mydistance)
      if mydistance !=0:
        distances.append(mydistance)

  return round(sum(distances)/len(distances),4)
```

Book solution

```
import math
Point2D = tuple[int,int]
def average_distance(points: set[Point2D]) -> float:
  if len(points) < 2:
    raise ValueError
  num_of_pairs = 0
  total_dist = 0.0
  for p1 in points:
    for p2 in points:
      if p1 != p2:
        num_of_pairs+=1
        total_dist += math.sqrt((p1[0]-p2[0])**2 + (p1[1]-p2[1])**2)
  return total_dist/num_of_pairs
```